# How to test a github repo mkdocs built files locally on Mac OS X?

Tags: read-the-docs, mkdocs

There's a GitHub repo I like to [make changes to its docs](https://github.com/igordejanovic/textX/issues/143). It uses readthedocs to host and mkdocs for the theme.

I am using macOS Mojave.

I found this https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html installation guide to install `readthedocs`. But I don't see how I can test the built files after I change the `mkdocs.yml` file of the repo I want to make changes to.

So how do I test the built files for readthedocs when I make changes to the `mkdocs.yml` locally in macOS X?

I don't mind using docker if that's necessary.

Comment: what do you mean by testing, unit testing or integrating testing or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mental model of the problem is wrong. ReadTheDocs is simply a service that uses a documentation generator (either sphinx or mkdocs) and hosts the output files generated.

To run mkdocs locally, simply:

1. fork the repo
2. clone the fork locally
3. setup a suitable virtual environment (since textX is a python library and so is mkdocs)
4. install the suitable required libraries stated in `requirements.txt` or `requirements_dev.txt` depending on the repo
5. run `mkdocs serve`

The mkdocs will run locally at `127.0.0.1:8000` for you to test the generated html files. To make changes to the mkdocs config, go to the `mkdocs.yml`

Comment: What if there is no requirements.txt like here : https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/tree/master/docs